# apache poi comments author missed

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.8 and trying to run a cell comment example for HSSF sheet with code below, but it misses author in the comment

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); //or new HSSFWorkbook();

    CreationHelper factory = wb.getCreationHelper();

    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

    Row row  = sheet.createRow(3);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(5);
    cell.setCellValue("asdads");

    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
    anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex()+5);
    anchor.setRow1(row.getRowNum());
    anchor.setRow2(row.getRowNum()+2);

    // Create the comment and set the text+author
    Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
    RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString("Hello, World! the new world");
    comment.setAuthor("roy");
    comment.setString(str);
    comment.setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
    // Assign the comment to the cell
    cell.setCellComment(comment);

    System.out.println(comment.getAuthor());

    String fname = "C:/Users/roy/Desktop/comment.xls";

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fname);
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
```

[image: here is the generated output and expected output]
Please suggest any idea

Comment: Why you setting setVisible(false)? do you see the comment?

Comment: I want comments only to be visible on mouse over, but this has nothing to do with the Author

Comment: Ok, code seems to be allright, don't know why you don't see author, can you attach your result xls?

Comment: please review the image

Comment: It seems to be a minor bug. You can just set the author name as part of setText() till the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As @Avik pointed out above, this can be easily set ... and I don't think that's a bug, because in Office this is just a convenience function as a comment doesn't need to start with the author name and you can remove it ...

```
String author = "roy";
Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString(author+":\nHello, World! the new world");
str.applyFont(0, author.length()+2, font);
comment.setAuthor(author);
comment.setString(str);
comment.setVisible(Boolean.FALSE);
// Assign the comment to the cell
cell.setCellComment(comment);
```